# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context SOMETIMES

Tags: mysql, join

I get so annoyed when I transfer websites from one machine to another and I get a bunch of errors, such as this case. But this one made it to my curiosity and this is why I'm asking a question. I have the following code:

```
namsepace MF;
class Box {
    private static $dumpYard = array();

    public static function get($name) {
        return self::$dumpYard[$name];
    }

    public static function set($name, $value, $overwrite=false) {
        if($overwrite || !isset(self::$dumpYard[$name])){
            self::$dumpYard[$name] = $value;
        }else{
            if(DEBUG_MODE){
                echo('Value for "'.$name.'" already set in box, can\'t overwrite');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when my application gets to the following line on my LOCAL testing server:

```
if(!empty(\MF\Box::get('requestsSpam'))){
    throw new \Exception('Please don\'t spam');
}
```

I get a **Fatal error**: Can't use function return value in write context. However this code does not throw an error on the actual hosting server of my website. How come is that?

Answer (score 3):

`empty()` works only with a variable. It should be:

```
$result = \MF\Box::get('requestsSpam');
if(!empty($result)){
    throw new \Exception('Please don\'t spam');
}
```

Why? `empty()` is a language construct and not a function. It will work only with declared variables, that's just how it is designed, no magic.

Comment: Yeah I figured that, my question was why I am getting a **FATAL** error on one server and not on another, the versions of php on which are 5.5 and 5.4

Comment: The configs are the same?

Comment: Well what configuration options does `empty()` depend on?

Comment: `empty()` don't depend on configuration values. But it could be that `display_errors` value differs

Comment: In debug mode I have `display_errors()` set to `E_ALL` in both cases

Comment: Are you sure that the `if(!empty(..` code block will being entered on both systems?

Comment: Yes, in 5.4.4 it's throwing a fatal error, on php 5.5 it works as expected

Comment: @php_nub_qq Interesting news... Let's check the changelog! :) (will answer tomorrow... I'm tired for today........)